# How to send_file() in response to form submission in Turbo-Flask python

Tags: python, flask, turbo

I have a fairly simple Flask application that response to a form submission with a xlsx file after some processing. I've been trying to change the webapp to use Turbo-Flask, however due to the way Turbo-Flask changes how form submissions work, my current implementation no longer works. I've tried reading some documentation, however the Turbo-Flask docs are fairly limited, and I don't have any experience with Turbo outside of this context.
Was just wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing, a simple redirect etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn off turbo for given form/link with `data-turbo="false"` attribute.

Other than that, you need to explain your question a bit more for me to help you.